# cloning submodule fails

Tags: git, drupal, git-submodules

I am trying to clone a submodule for my drupal installation. I run the following command:

```
git submodule add http://git.drupal.org/project/token.git /sites/all/modules/token
```

This throws this error:

```
The following path is ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
/sites/all/modules/token
Use -f if you really want to add it.
```

But my .gitignore file is empty.

So I tried to run it as suggested:

```
submodule add -f http://git.drupal.org/project/token.git /sites/all/modules/token
```

But this throws this error:

```
fatal: could not create leading directories of '/sites/all/modules/token': Permission denied
Clone of 'http://git.drupal.org/project/token.git' into submodule path '/sites/all/modules/token' failed
```

Permissions are 777.

Ideas?

Regards
Lukas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found the answer:

```
git submodule add http://git.drupal.org/project/token.git sites/all/modules/token
```

The leading "/" was the problem.

Comment: Any idea why that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but apparently for different reasons. I tried to use `git submodule add` like I used `git clone` - without specifying the directory like this:

`git submodule add ../repos/subA` instead of `git submodule add ../repos/subA subA`

All I have to say is that is the effing worst error message possible to tell me I left off a required command-line argument.